# How to join two table using jon in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select

I have two tables events and sessions, They look like the following

```
events

id  sid
1   10
2   10
3   20
4   20
6   ter4
7   576
```

second table

```
sessions

id  sid
1   10
2   10
3   20
4   20
6   e21
7   b34
```

Here is what I would like the result to look from the above tables, Expected result

```
Total_sessions  Total_equal_sessions
7               4
```

Now when I run the following query

```
SELECT sessions.sid, COUNT(*) AS Total_sessions, COUNT( sessions.sid ) AS Total_equal_sessions 
FROM events RIGHT JOIN sessions ON events.sid = sessions.sid
```

I get the following result

```
Total_sessions  Total_equal_sessions
7               7
```

What do I need to do to get what I want?

Comment: Please explain how those values are calculated.  In particular, how do you get 7 sessions?

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`. What you have now `COUNT( sessions.sid )` is equivalent to `COUNT(*)`

Comment: @gordon what do you mean I think I have explained in my question?

Comment: BTW that RIGHT JOIN should produce 10, not 7 rows. The `sid`s are repeated, so all combinations will appear in the results. Which means, that even the `COUNT(*)` won't be 7

Comment: @user9964622 post the correct test data and desired outcome, explaining where it came from. Right now you're asking people to create the tables from scratch and try to guess what you actually want from data that doesn't match what you ask.

Comment: Did you want to join by `id` instead of `sid` perhaps?

Comment: @user9964622 . . . You have six identical ids in each table ("5" is missing).  You have 12 rows and 6 distinct values for `sid`.  The "7" is totally mysterious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a little more data to count the matched sids - in this case I have used a generated row number. The total sessions just appears to be the max id from second table.

```
drop table if exists t,t1;
create table t
(id int, sid varchar(10));
insert into t values
(1  , '10'),
(2  , '10'),
(3  , '20'),
(4  , '20'),
(6  , 'ter4'),
(7  , '576');

create table t1
(id int, sid varchar(10));
insert into t1 values
(1  , '10'),
(2  , '10'),
(3  , '20'),
(4  , '20'),
(6  , 'A'),
(7  , 'b');

select (select max(id) from t1) sessions,sum(case when t1.sid1 = t.sid and t1.rn1 = t.rn then 1 else 0 end) matched
from
(select sid,row_number() over (partition by sid order by sid) rn from t) t
right join
(select sid sid1,row_number() over (partition by sid order by sid) rn1 from t1) t1
on t1.sid1 = t.sid and t1.rn1 = t.rn


+----------+---------+
| sessions | matched |
+----------+---------+
|        7 |       4 |
+----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
COUNT(sessions.sid)
```

Will simply count all rows where sid is not null. You probably want:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT sessions.sid)
```

Also you seem to have sid in the events table that is not in sessions table (ter4) and vice versah - right join will exclude rows from events which dont have a corresponding entry in sessions - is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left join, count(id) from the left side table will return the Total_sessions, count(id) from the right side table will return count for all not null values in this case all the values that match in both tables.

Here is an example

```
create table #events(id int, sid varchar(10))
create table #sessions(id int, sid varchar(10))

insert #events
select * from (values(1,'10'),(2,'10'),(3,'20'),(4,'20'),(5,'abc'),(6,'ter4'),(7,'576')) a(id,sid)

insert #sessions
select * from (values(1,'10'),(2,'10'),(3,'20'),(4,'20'),(5,'xyz'),(6,'e21'),(7,'b34')) a(id,sid)

select count(e.id) Total_sessions, count(s.id) Total_equal_sessions
  from #events e left join
       #sessions s on e.id = s.id and e.sid = s.sid
```